# отправляю письмо через Powetshell, как задать кодировку теме и телу письма?

Tags: powershell

Делаю скрипт чтобы он отправлял письмо. Все работает но тема и тело письма приходит в иероглифах, не могу разобраться как добавить кодировку, может кто подсказать?

```
#Адрес сервера SMTP для отправки
$serverSmtp = "smtp.yandex.ru" 
#Порт сервера
$port = 587
#От кого
$From = "login@yandex.ru" 
#Кому
$To = "login@yandex.ru" 
#Тема письма
$subject = "Test с вложением"
#Логин и пароль от ящики с которого отправляете login@yandex.ru
$user = "login@yandex.ru"
$pass = "password"
$Body = "Telo письма"
#Путь до файла, пример: "C:\arhive.zip"
$file = C:\arhive.zip
#Создаем два экземпляра класса
$att = New-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
$mes = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
#Формируем данные для отправки
$mes.From = $from
$mes.To.Add($to) 
$mes.Subject = $subject 
$mes.IsBodyHTML = $true 
$mes.Body = $Body
#Добавляем файл
$mes.Attachments.Add($att) 
#Создаем экземпляр класса подключения к SMTP серверу 
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($serverSmtp, $port)
#Сервер использует SSL 
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true 
#Создаем экземпляр класса для авторизации на сервере 
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass);
#Отправляем письмо, освобождаем память
$smtp.Send($mes)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150563/powershell-mail-encoding  Не подойдёт?

Comment: попытался добавить вот такую строчку в скрипт - 
$mes.BodyEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 но это не помогло

Comment: поставил кодировку текста в скрипте "UTF8 с BOM" все заработало, даже без параметра BodyEncoding